# Closure call with mismatched arguments: in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting following error while using callback

```
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_MyAppState.callback'
Receiver: Closure: (String) => void from Function 'callback':.
Tried calling: _MyAppState.callback(value: "1")
Found: _MyAppState.callback(String) => void
```

I have recreated same error in following sample code Please help me to solve it.
Thank you

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_error/keyboard.dart';
import 'package:my_error/title.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  void callback(String value){
    setState(() {
      MyTitle.title += value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(MyTitle.title),
        ),
        body: MyKeyboard(callback: callback,),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

keyboard.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_error/button.dart';

class MyKeyboard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function callback;

  const MyKeyboard({
    required this.callback,
    Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Btn(disp: "1", callback: callback),
        Btn(disp: "2", callback: callback)

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

button.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Btn extends StatelessWidget {
  final disp;
  final Function callback;
  const Btn({
    required this.disp,
    required this.callback,
    Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {callback(value:disp.toString());},
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*10/100,
        child: Text(disp,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36,color:Colors.white),),

      ),
    ) ;
  }
}
```

I had to setstate of _MyAppState class from stateless widget (MyKeyboard) which further carry forward callback function to another stateless widget (Btn) form here onTap callback function is called.

But I am getting above mentioned error

Comment: `Btn` invokes `callback` with the assumption that the callback has a *named* `String` parameter named `value`.  However, the actual `_MyAppState.callback` function has a *positional* `String` parameter.  Either remove `value:` in `Btn` or make `_MyAppState.callback`'s parameter a required named parameter.  Also use strong typing and change the various `final Function callback;` declarations to use the specific function type (e.g. `final void Function(String) callback;`).